# Правильная работа с запросом Lucene.Net

Tags: java, c#, lucene

Есть некоторый текст в котором мне нужно найти некоторые слова
Для этого я пытаюсь использовать такой запрос

```
"C++" OR "Boost" OR "STLSoft" OR "STLPort" OR "C++ Templated Image Processing Library" ...
```

Запрос в целом работает верно, но по какой то причине в момент вызова QueryParser.Parse следующий запрос преобразуется в это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У слова "C++" отбрасываются "++", из-за чего поиск происходит не верно.
Как экранировать знак "+" в запросе? Так же, я заметил что при поиске через Lucene.Net, отбрасываются окончания. Как мне сделать так, чтобы запрос бы аналогичным методу Contains ignore case?

Comment: Быть может `C\+\+` поможет? А может поисковый движок намеренно выкидывает спец символы.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, все так же удаляет все не буквенные символы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы передаёте какой-нибудь SimpleAnalyzer или StandradAnalyzer в парсер запросов. Эти аналайзеры отбрасывают не буквенные символы при токенизации.

Из неотбрасывющих есть WhiteSpaceAnalyzer, но он регистрозависимый.

Вы можете реализовать аналайзер самостоятельно.

```
public class IgnoreCaseAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    private readonly LuceneVersion matchVersion;

    public IgnoreCaseAnalyzer(LuceneVersion matchVersion)
    {
        this.matchVersion = matchVersion;
    }

    protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        return new TokenStreamComponents(new LowerCaseAnySymbolTokenizer(matchVersion, reader));
    }
}

public sealed class LowerCaseAnySymbolTokenizer : CharTokenizer
{
    public LowerCaseAnySymbolTokenizer(LuceneVersion matchVersion, TextReader @in)
        : base(matchVersion, @in) { }    

    public LowerCaseAnySymbolTokenizer(LuceneVersion matchVersion, AttributeFactory factory, TextReader @in)
        : base(matchVersion, factory, @in) { }

    protected override bool IsTokenChar(int c)
    {
        return !Character.IsWhiteSpace(c);
    }

    protected override int Normalize(int c)
    {
        return Character.ToLower(c, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Имейте ввиду, что логично применять один и тот же аналайзер при построении индекса и при запросах к нему. Иначе вы будете искать по токенам, которых нет в индексе.

Ещё может быть важно, что [StandardAnalyzer](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/51cc7418adf9da96cd37dd64ff5085d752a54074/src/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/Analysis/Standard/StandardAnalyzer.cs) умеет убирать стоп слова и обрезать через чур длинные токены. В некоторых датасетах это может положительно влиять на производительность и размер индекса. Вы можете расширить пример выше, если это актуально для вашего приложения.